# Como faço para a barra de rolagem funcionar na minha página inteira no chrome

Tags: html

Como faço para a barra de rolagem funcionar na minha página inteira no chrome, no mozila funciona normalmente

```
<?php
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=uft-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
    <script src="js/camera.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow/wow.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) {
                new WOW().init();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative; background: #fff;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
            <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0"
                 height="42" width="820"
                 alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."/>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <script>
        //função para ativar o scroll nos navegadores ex: chrome
       window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
           const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
           const scrolled = window.scrollY;


           if (Match.ceil(scrolled) === scrollable){
              alert('está com o Scroll funcionando no chrome'!);
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="page">
<!--========================================================
                          HEADER
=========================================================-->
<header id="header">
    <div id="stuck_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <div class="brand">
                        <h1>
                            <a href="./">
                                <img src="images/logo.png">

                            </a>
                        </h1>
                    </div>

                    <nav>
                        <ul class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="current"><a href="./">Início</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="fa fa-caret-down" href="index-2.html">Produtos</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sistemas para corretoras</a>
                                                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">SixVox</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">SixVox Free Lance</a></li>
                                        </ul></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Guia Médico</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Implantação de CRM</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="index-3.html">Novidades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-1.html">Quem Somos </a></li>

                            <li><a href="index-4.html">Contatos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</div>
<!--========================================================
                          CONTENT
=========================================================-->
<section id="content">
<div class="camera-wrapper">
    <div id="camera" class="camera_wrap">
        <div data-src="images/index-slide01.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn bg_3 color_8">
                <h2 class="text_5">
                    Nossas soluções inteligentes<br/>
                    tornam suas idéias<br/>
                    realidade!
                </h2>

                <p class="text_6">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
                </p>
                <!--<a class="btn_1" href="#">See all products <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></span></a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-src="images/index-slide02.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn bg_4 color_8">
                <h2 class="text_5">
                    Simples. Impressionante. <br/>
                    Inteligente.
                </h2>

                <p class="text_6">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
                </p>
                <!--<a class="btn_1" href="#">See all products <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></span></a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-src="images/index-slide03.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn bg_1 color_6">
                <h2 class="text_5">
                    Uma linha completa de sistemas
                </h2>

                <p class="text_6">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
                </p>
                <!--<a class="btn_1" href="#">See all products <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></span></a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg_2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid_12 wow fadeInLeft">
                <h2 class="header_1 text_7 color_8">
                    Soluções inteligentes para potencializar o seu sucesso. <br/>
                    Vendas - Administração - Gerenciamento - Relacionamento
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_12 wow fadeInLeft">
            <h2 class="header_2 text_7 color_6">Soluções IdeiaVox</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_6 wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="box_1 bg_1 maxheight">
                <div class="put-right maxheight2">
                    <img src="images/index_img01.jpg" alt="Image 1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3 class="text_8 color_6">
                        <a href="#">Mantenha o foco em seus negócios.</a>
                    </h3>

                    <p class="text_6 color_10">
                        Conheça as soluções da IdeiaVox para empresas. <br/>
                        Oferecemos serviços e valor sem que você precise fazer 
                        um alto investimento em infra estrutura própria.
                    </p>




                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_6  wow fadeInRight">
            <div class="box_1 bg_4 maxheight">
                <div class="bg_image_1 maxheight2"></div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/sixvox.png" border="0"><br>O sistema das corretoras</a>
                    </h3>

                    <p class="text_6 color_8">
                       Sixvox é a solução mais completa para concessionárias e repasses. O sistema é amplamente utilizado pelo mercado
                        e hoje já atende a corretoras de diversos portes
                    </p>

                    <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="http://www.sixvox.com.br">
                        Saiba mais
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_3 md_grid_6  wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="box_2 bg_3 maxheight1 last-row">
                <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                    <a href="#">
                        Implantação de CRM- <br/>
                        Suite CRM
                    </a>
                </h3>

                <p class="text_6 color_8">
                   O gerenciamento do relacionamento com clientes e do funil de vendas é um diferencial importante. 
                   Suite CRM é umas das mais conceituadas ferramentas open source para essa finalidade.
                </p>

                <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="#">Saiba mais</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3 md_grid_6  wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="box_2 bg_2 maxheight1 last-row">
                <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                    <a href="#">Guia Médico Rio</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="text_6 color_8">
                    Guia Médico.Rio é uma solução para que une os clientes aos prestadores de serviço 
                    ao mesmo tempo que agrega um moderno sistema para marcação de consultas.
                </p>

                <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="http://guiamedico.rio">Saiba mais</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_6  wow fadeInRight">
            <div class="box_1 bg_6 last-row">
                <div class="put-right"><img src="images/index_img03.jpg" alt="Image 3"/></div>
                <div class="inner  maxheight1 ">
                    <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                        <a href="#">TI Centro</a>
                    </h3>

                    <p class="text_6 color_8">
                        Suporte em informática é oferecido para empresas através da TI Centro. 
                        Se sua empresa necessita de suporte em informática entre em contato conosco.
                    </p>

                    <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="http://www.ticentro.com.br">Saiba mais</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_12 wow fadeInLeft">
            <h2 class="header_3 text_7 color_6">IdeiaVox</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_12 wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="wrapper_1">
                <div class="box_3 last-row">
                    <h3 class="text_8 color_1">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                        ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
                    </h3>

                    <p class="text_6 color_10">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                        ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita- <br/>
                        tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit in
                        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <br/>
                        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                    </p>

                    <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_7" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg_6">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid_12 wow fadeInLeft">
                <h2 class="header_4 text_7 color_8">Nossos Serviços</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid_6 wow fadeInLeft">
                <div class="box_4">
                    <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                        <span class="put-left">
                            <span class="icon  bg_3 color_8 fa fa-briefcase"></span>
                        </span>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit.
                    </h3>

                    <p class="text_6 color_9">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid- <br/>
                        unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita- <br/>
                        tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_6 wow fadeInRight">
                <div class="box_4">
                    <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                        <span class="put-left">
                            <span class="icon bg_4 color_8 fa fa-pencil"></span>
                        </span>

                        Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est l
                    </h3>

                    <p class="text_6 color_9">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid- <br/>
                        unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita- <br/>
                        tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper_2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_6 wow fadeInLeft">
                    <div class="box_4 last-row">
                        <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                            <span class="put-left">
                                <span class="icon bg_2 color_8 fa fa-book"></span>
                            </span>
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident
                        </h3>

                        <p class="text_6 color_9">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid-
                            <br/>
                            unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita- <br/>
                            tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="#">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6 wow fadeInRight">
                    <div class="box_4 last-row">
                        <h3 class="text_8 color_8">
                            <span class="put-left">
                                <span class="icon bg_1 color_6 fa fa-lock"></span>
                            </span>
                            Ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit.
                        </h3>

                        <p class="text_6 color_9">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid-
                            <br/>
                            unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita- <br/>
                            tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        <a class="btn_2 text_3 color_8" href="#">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<!--========================================================
                          FOOTER
=========================================================
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="bg_1 wrapper_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <h2 class="header_5 text_3 color_6">Company</h2>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ctetur adipisicing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Do eiusmod tempor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incididunt ut labore</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Et dolore magna</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Minim veniam</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <h2 class="header_5 text_3 color_6">Products</h2>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Ctetur adipisicing </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Do eiusmod tempor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incididunt ut labore</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Et dolore magna </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Minim veniam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Quis nostrud set </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ullamco laboris nis</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_3 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                    <h2 class="header_5 text_3 color_6">Partnerships</h2>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Do eiusmod tempor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incididunt ut labore </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Et dolore magna</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Minim veniam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Quis nostrud set</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ullamco laboris nis</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_3 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                    <h2 class="header_5 text_3 color_6">Follow Us</h2>
                    <ul class="social-list">
                        <li><a class="fa fa-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="fa fa-rss" href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid_12">
                <div class="info text_11"><a href="./">Software©</a> 2014. <a href="index-5.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                    More <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemonster.com/category.php?category=346&type=1" target="_blank">Software Company Templates at TemplateMonster.com</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
-->
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: melhora um pouco a pergunta não so cola o código fica ruim pra ajudar.

Comment: obrigado sou novo aqui, um amigo me passou este site,como faço pra retirar o código que postei, e só ir a parte que interessa?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask da uma lida, mas no geral isole um exemplo, e descreva o que você quer, quanto mais fácil de entender seu problema mais fácil das pessoas ajudarem.

Comment: estou com um site mas a barra de scroll aparece e funciona apenas no firefox, no chrome não, inclui um código java script,recentemente

Comment: segue o código agora as barras aparecem no chrome porém não move a tela central apenas se eu clicar nas barras laterais, como resolvo isso?

Comment: o código abaixo:<script>
        //função para ativar o scroll nos navegadores ex: chrome
       window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
           const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
           const scrolled = window.scrollY;
           
        
           if (Match.ceil(scrolled) === scrollable){
              alert('está com o Scroll funcionando no chrome'!);
    });
    
    </script>

Comment: Isso, mas edita a pergunta e coloca essa informações lá. que ja vou olhar pra tentar te ajudar.

Comment: como faço pra ativar a barra de scroll no chrome? somente no mozila ela funciona, me ajudem

Comment: Coloca o CSS na pergunta para podermos tentar reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Tem 2 erros no código: Falta fechar o `if (Math.ceil(scrolled) === scrollable){` e em vez de `Match.ceil`, o correto é `Math.ceil`.

Comment: sam eu fiz o que me disse  e deixei assim  da uma olhada no código <script>
        //função para ativar o scroll nos navegadores ex: chrome
       window.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
           const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
           const scrolled = window.scrollY;
           
        
           if (Math.ceil(scrolled) === scrollable){
              
    });
        } 
    
    </script>

Comment: <script>
        //função para ativar o scroll nos navegadores ex: chrome
       window.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
           const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
           const scrolled = window.scrollY;
           
        
           if (Math.ceil(scrolled) === scrollable){
              
    });
        } 
    
    </script>

Comment: Seu problema é com algum script bloqueando o scroll wheel no body, se vc colocar um `    margin-left: 100px;` na tag HTML, vai dar um espaço vazio a esquerda, se vc colocar o mouse ali e fizer o scroll com o mouse wheel vc vai ver que no html o scroll funciona, mas no body não!! Outro teste é vc remover todos os `.js` do site e vc vai ver que o Scroll volta a funcionar. Então seu problema é algum desses JS que está interferindo no body de alguma forma! Sugiro que vc remova um por um até achar o qual deles está bugando a página

Comment: achei o javascript que bloqueia mas ele é a chamada do javascript, e sem ele as imagem não carregam.

Comment: obrigado a todos pela ajuda era uma classe no javascript, agradecimentos em especial ao  hugocs!,exclui uma classe que era pra suaviar mousewheel, que bloqueava no chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um estilo no elemento que você quer tenha barra de rolagem:

```
style="overflow: auto"
```

Exemplo:

```
<html>
 <head>
  ...
</head>
<body style="overflow: auto">
  ...
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Mas o body já tem overflow: auto!! Ou algum dia vc precisou dizer no seu CSS que o scroll deveria aparecer no body?

Comment: O body era apenas um exemplo, você tem que colocar esse estilo aonde você quer que tenha a barra de rolagem.

Comment: E pq no Firefox funciona a rolagem e no Chrome não tem rolagem?

Comment: esse é o meu problema no chrome, não funciona, fiz o que me falou Marcelo Martins, mas continua sem rolar no chrome,já não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Algum dos teus css está fazendo isso, tente comentar alguns arquivos .css para ver qual deles está removendo a barra de rolagem.

Comment: a barra aparece,no chrome, mas s[o funciona se clicar nela, no canto direito

Comment: de uma olhada na página: http://nova.ideiavox.com.br

Comment: Tinha entendi errado tua pergunta....... tente remover do teu css essa class: "noscroll"

Comment: não achei essa classe